# pegar a linha que tem um '1x' nela e tudo dps dela até o proximo '1x'

Tags: javascript

Em um array de varias linhas que seria meio que uma comanda de pedido eu preciso separar em um novo array cada um dos itens, que são prefixados com um '1x', ai eu preciso pegar esse 1x e os complementos que vem logo nas próximas linhas, e quando aparecer o próximo '1x' gerar outro array.

```
Array(10)  (esse é o array inicial)
0: "Itens do pedido"
1: "1x X - Tudo"
2: "- COMPLETO"
3: "1x Coca-cola 2L"
4: "1x Pastel Frango"
5: "- Ovo"
6: "- Calabresa"
7: "- Bacon"
8: "Queijo"
9: "- Catupiry"
```

Resumindo: eu preciso do x-tudo e o complemento dele(no caso o completo) / so a coca / e o pastel e seus complementos...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse codigo foi baseado no chatGPT, a intenção seria q ele pegasse o 1x e oq estivesse depois dele, mas não funcionou!

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Array(10)
0: "Itens do pedido"
1: "1x X - Tudo"
2: "- COMPLETO"
3: "1x Coca-cola 2L"
4: "1x Pastel Frango"
5: "- Ovo"
6: "- Calabresa"
7: "- Bacon"
8: "Queijo"
9: "- Catupiry"

Comment: E o item "Queijo" deve ser considerado como complemento já que não inicia com "1x"?

Answer (score -2):

se você esta procurando iterar sobre uma array de textos e retornar uma nova array somente com os textos que tiverem uma palavra especifica. você poderar fazer assim

```
const texto = ['1x ola tudo bem ', 'ola', '1x ola tudo', 'ola tudo bem'];
const palavra = '1x'

const result = texto.filter((elemento) => elemento.includes(palavra));

console.log(result);
```

o metodo filter() irar retornar uma nova array somente com os elementos que passarem no teste. ja o metodo includes() irar retornar true se o elemento tiver a palavra especificada